# How to run a function from a string vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function

What i am trying to do is call functions from a string that I created

The example would be:
genoutput is a string I made to concatenate the function calls when a certain combo box item was selected...

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles Button2.Click
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        Case "First Name"
            genoutput = genoutput & randomfirstname() & vbTab
        Case "Last Name"
            genoutput = genoutput & randomlastname() & vbTab
        Case "Decimal"
            genoutput = genoutput & gendecimal(CDbl(decimal1.text,decimal2.text)) & vbtab )
        Case "Integer"
            genoutput = (genoutput & geninteger(CInt(integer1.text,integer2.text)) & vbtab)
        Case "Birthday"
            genoutput = (genoutput & birthday(CInt(year1.text,year2.text)) & vbtab &)
    End Select
```

I am trying to get a string that looks like this and runs

```
 outfile.Write(randomfirstname() & vbTab & randomlastname() & vbTab & gendecimal(CDbl(decimal1.text,decimal2.text)) & vbTab & (CInt(integer1.text,integer2.text)) & vbTab & birthday(CInt(year1.text,year2.text)) & vbCrLf)
```

Comment: My advice would be to rethink your solution so you don't need to do this. This seems like a really kludgy approach.

Comment: Instead of building a string to call a function to get another string, why not just build the final output string and get rid of the unnecessary middle man?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you remove the quotes from `hello() & vbtab & goodbye()`, but as JohnFx said, it seems like an unusual and unnecessary way to do it.

Comment: This is for a bigger issue i had on another program.. I just added this simple problem because it effectively showed my issue... I didn't know it would be that easy... thanks :)

Comment: The point is to store something in the list that you can use in a case block to decide which code to run. Don't intermix code and data like you are attempting.

Comment: The edit looks OK, but I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do.

Comment: same as last time... I took out the quotes and the simple ones with no parameters were working.. but as soon as there was a comma in the block of code it was saying it was an error

Comment: cInt and cDbl only accept a single parameter. Instead of using cInt and cDbl, you can use the Format function to accept numeric values and format them as a formatted string:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h(VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for something more like:

1) ListBox1.Items.Add("Hello"), .Add("Goodbye"), ...

2) If ListBox1.ListIndex = 0 then call hello, else if ...